# Перенос Visual Studio Community на комп без доступа к интернету

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Пользуюсь для разработки VS Com 19. Есть два рабочих места - дома и на работе, где нельзя в принципе организовать выход в СЕТЬ, машина автономна. Можно ли перенести лицензию, если её можно так назвать, на этот комп. Копирование папки /%LocalAppData%/VSCommon/OnlineLicense/ не помогает

Comment: Наверное вопросами лицензирования рабочего ПО должен озаботиться работодатель. Visual Studio Community между прочим имеет серьезные ограничения на использование в организациях.

Comment: @user7860670 это так же мой компьютер, не корпоративный, используется только в моих личных целях

Comment: снимаешь HDD и тащишь домой :) `в принципе организовать выход в СЕТЬ` - даже через мобилу?

Comment: @Виталий-Шебаниц даже через мобилу. Режим такой в этом месте. Из компов изъяты батареи питания и модули wi-fi